# amazon api gateway returns 403

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am calling a serverless api(apigateway+lambda) from lambda from another aws account with axios, returns 403 http status with payload `{ message: "Forbidden" }`. the get http call returns data when used in chrome

Comment: double check your HTTP method and your path. That is common answer from API Gateway when there is no method + path deployed for the request that you sent. The best way to check is copy the url from the console. Copy from the "Stage".

Comment: @GustavoTavares it returns data when called in browser, it returns 403 when called from another lambda.

Comment: Is there anything in `x-amzn-ErrorType` response header? From your lambda request?

Comment: @GustavoTavares x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException

Comment: Your Lambda Function is inside a VPC? The serverless api or a lambda from the other account? Your api gateway is protected by WAF?

Comment: @Niyaz Did you find a solution to this? I am running into the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

looking at the comments which say that the headers included "x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException", that happened for me when I had not deployed the api yet.  After deploying the api, that error went away